# add another layout to this layout while jsonarray exist

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout

im trying to create something like timeline feed
its mean like Tango newsfeed
i get Json array JUST like this:

```
{"salam":[{"matn":"something","user_esm":"some name","user_image":"image url","liked":1,"followed":0,"user_id":"hfgdlerm"},{"matn":"something 2","user_esm":"other name","user_image":"iamge url","liked":1,"followed":0,"user_id":"hfgdlerm",}
```

and custom layout like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="124dp"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_weight="0.24" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and HOme.java with default layout like this:

```
public class home extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("userPref", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    String useridnow = pref.getString("userid", null);
    if(useridnow == null) {
        Intent i = new Intent(home.this,MainActivity.class);
       home.this.startActivity(i);
    }
    new Getfeed(home.this,useridnow).execute();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
class Getfeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
private String userid;
private Context context;
RelativeLayout rellay;

public Getfeed(Context context, String userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://fb.facenegah.com/android/showfeed.php");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("feedid","0"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("limit", "1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", userid));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uper", "0"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("downer", "0"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("isprofile", "0"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        return responseText;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    JSONObject jsonResponse;
   //Toast.makeText(context, "Json: "+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        jsonResponse = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONArray movies = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("salam");

        for(int i=0;i<movies.length();i++){
            JSONObject movie = movies.getJSONObject(i);
            String characters = movie.getString("user_esm");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Json: "+characters , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView.setText(characters);
            //setListAdapter(rowView);
           // final ListView listview = (ListView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listView);



        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
}
```

i just dont know how use that custom layout and full its textview and imageview while json array exist and show them on home activity just like timeline
i try setadapter and otherthing ... but its not work
please help me with this

Comment: can you give me example? im noob in android and just know php very well

Comment: take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Comment: cant understand it :(